# GA4 Entrances metric in Reporting API

Tags: google-analytics-4

In Google Analytics 4 documentation, there is a description of what entrances is in [Entrances & Exists](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11080047?hl=en).

> Entrances and exits show you how many times the first or last event in
> a session happened on a page or screen

But when looking into [Reporting API Dimensions & Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema), I cannot find any metric equivalent to entrances.

Is there a way to get entrances with the reporting API?

Answer (score 0):

The *screenPageViews* metric but with the *landingPagePath* dimension seems to work. At least if I request screenPageViews with a filter of landingPagePath = URL I get a different, much smaller number than if I request screenPageViews with a filter of pagePath = URL.

Although comparing this between UA and GA4 for one of the pages on my site, I do see that the Page views are very similar between UA and GA4 but the UA Entrances are quite a bit smaller than the GA4 Page views for landing page.

| Month | UA Entrances | UA pageviews | % | GA4 views by landing | GA4 views by path | % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| April | 334 | 1979 | 17% | 542 | 1995 | 27% |
| May | 1778 | 6649 | 27% | 2526 | 6713 | 38% |
| June | 548 | 3168 | 17% | 1052 | 3182 | 33% |
| July | 423 | 3294 | 13% | 846 | 3305 | 26% |

Comment: >I request screenPageViews with a filter of landingPagePath = URL

What do you mean by filter of landingPagePath = URL?

Comment: *filter* is the way of narrowing down the query to only return a subset. Pretty much every way to do a GA4 query uses that name, e.g. the GA4 Explore tool, Looker Studio, the GA4 Query Explorer.

*landingPagePath* is the GA4 dimension name.

*URL* is me saying that I am restricting my query to only one URL. The test I reported above used one of the pages on my site, and URL is just the filename of that page.